# Is this the correct syntax when using multiple criteria with the find command?

Tags: shell, find

```
find -user kyle -ctime -1 -type f -size -100M
```

I want to find all files on my system created by user Kyle, in the last 24 hours, and less than a 100 MB

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: need to specify start directory in first argument

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help try this

```
find "$PWD" -type f -user Kyle -ctime -1 -size -100M
```

or

```
find . -type f -user Kyle -ctime -1 -size -100M
```

If want to restrict to only 1 level or 2 level or any level directories

you can use : `-maxdepth 1` or `-mindepth 1`

Want to search certain extension make use of `-name "*.jpg"` like below

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -user Kyle -ctime -1 -size -100M
```

If required any changes feel free to edit it